# CakePHP: Limit Fields associated with a model

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model, sql-limit

I have several fields in some of my database tables that my CakePHP models never need to retrieve. Is there some way to set a default set of fields to fetch at the model level? For instance I retrieve some data from a third party designed database that has 50 fields per table, I use 5.

I know I can set limits on fields at the time of the find() query and at the time of any associations between models, but I was wondering if there was a model-level approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CakePHP does not offer what you describe at the Model level out of the box. That is to say there is no Model property of `defaultFields` that is used on every `find()`

As you noted, you could specify this at the association level by setting the `fields` property. However, this would only work when you were retrieving the Model across one of these relationships.

In the end, you're going to be setting this in your `find()`. You could minimize repeating yourself by adding a property to your model like so:

```
var $defaultFields = array('Model.field1', 'Model.field2', ...);
```

Then in your `find()`:

```
$this->Model->find('fields' => $this->Model->defaultFields, ...);
```

This has obvious limitations, but at least provides some encapsulation and therefore flexibility.

**Note:** A more invasive approach could use [`beforeFind();`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1049/beforeFind). In which case you would not need to adjust every `find()`. But your mileage may vary based on your usage.

Comment: That's what I figured, thanks though. I think I'll use that $default fields idea

Comment: No problem. If you have *simple* `find()`, using the `beforeFind()` callback might be a *quicker* approach. From my experience though, these callbacks can fire at unintuitive times.